# Create numpy array (contour) to be used with opencv functions

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to python and I don't know how to create numpy array that may be used in opencv functions. 
I've got two vectors defined as follows:

```
X=np.array(x_list)
Y=np.array(y_list)
```

and the result is:

```
[ 250.78  250.23  249.67 ...,  251.89  251.34  250.78]
[ 251.89  251.89  252.45 ...,  248.56  248.56  251.89]
```

I want to create opencv contour to be used in ex. `cv2.contourArea(contour)`. I read [Checking contour area in opencv using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369547/checking-contour-area-in-opencv-using-python) but cannot write my contour numpy array properly. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: It looks like cv2 contours are 3-dimensional numpy arrays. If you test out `contour.shape` you'll be able to work out it's dimensions. If you want to write a compatible numpy array it will need to have 3 dimensions. For example `numpy.zeros(1,2,3)` will create a 3D array of zeros of shape 1x2x3... Try testing that out!

Answer (score 2):

Here's some example code, that first checks the dimensions of a contour calculated from a test image, and makes a test array and has success with that as well. I hope this help you!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('output6.png',0) #read in a test image
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
im2,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)

cnt = contours[0]

print cnt.shape #this contour is a 3D numpy array
print cv2.contourArea(cnt) #the function prints out the area happily

#######Below is the bit you asked about

contour = np.array([[[0,0]], [[10,0]], [[10,10]], [[5,4]]]) #make a fake array
print cv2.contourArea(contour) #also compatible with function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is very usefull, altough my problem is that my input is not an image but contour points of a structure read from the file. Based on that i create binary image where contour points are ones, and background is 0. Applying cv2.findContours on that binary image results in finding many contours, but i know that there only should be one. That's why i wanted to artificially create the contour from the points, but i don't know how to put them into the structure like this: contour = np.array([[[0,0]], [[10,0]], [[10,10]], [[5,4]]])

Comment: this does not answer the question. this finds contours from an image.