# Area of aruco marker

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to find the area of an aruco marker. I use the following code to find the rectangle enclosing the marker:

```
corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(frame, aruco_dict, parameters=parameters)
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(corners[0])
```

Now how do I calculate the area from rect?

PS. OpenCV for Python doesn't have the best documentation so that's why I'm having issues doing the simplest of stuff.

Update:

Is this how I'm supposed to use rect and find the area?

```
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
area = cv2.contourArea(box)
```

Comment: Since each `corners[i]` consists of the 4 corners of a marker, you can easily compute its area like [in this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=area+of+polygon)

Comment: I was hoping there was a built in function which calculated it but I guess I can do it manually as well

Comment: [Here you go...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369547/checking-contour-area-in-opencv-using-python). You don't need `box` or `rect`, just apply `contourArea` to `corners[0]`